# How do I start certain services only when needed?

Tags: 12.04, upstart, services

I have a laptop. I use it for web+email a lot, and then some days for web development. Using it for the latter, I need apache2 and mysql server running, but normally I do not.

I'd like a normal boot to NOT start apache and mysql, to conserve power, reduce boot times etc. but then to be able to start these services when needed.

In the olden days I might have used runlevels for this, but that's a bit old skool now, as I understand. What's the best way to achieve this in Precise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A way to do it with good ol' runlevels:

**MySQL** now uses an upstart script, but inside that it's still talking about runlevels. Edit `/etc/init/mysql.conf` and change lines as in this diff:

```
-start on runlevel [2345]
-stop on starting rc RUNLEVEL=[016]
+start on runlevel [345]
+stop on starting rc RUNLEVEL=[0126]
```

**Apache2** still uses runlevel rc.N.d sym links:

```
sudo update-rc.d -f apache2 remove 
sudo update-rc.d apache2  start 91 3 4 5 . stop 09 0 1 6 .
```

Then on a normal boot (runlevel 2), they won't be started, and when you do `sudo telinit 3`, they will.

Comment: Why not add 2 as a stop to get apache2 stopped when going back to runlevel 2?

Comment: @Sylwester Yeah, you're right, just an oversight in my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

To stop mysql from starting at boot:

```
sudo echo "manual" | sudo tee /etc/init/mysql.override
```

To stop apache2 from starting at boot:

```
sudo update-rc.d apache2 disable 2
```

Whenever you need to start mysql or apache2 all you need to do is to start the service yourself (and you can also stop both manually).

You can use

```
sudo apache2ctl {start|stop|restart}
```

for that and

```
sudo service mysql {start|stop}
```

for mysql.

Comment: comment: I did the 1st 2 commands from memory (if they are wrong don't yell ;) but feel free to edit my answer).

Comment: yep it's `apache2ctl` nowadays (too small an edit to be allowed). Thanks: the first two are v. useful. The old runlevels were quite handy for this sort of thing. I sort of expected there to be an upstart way to trigger both apps to start (mysql needs to go before apache, ideally).

Comment: Your apache app breaking when mysql does not precede it is a fail BTW. Think about a datacenter power outtage.. the DB server might take a few more minutes than the webservers to come back up. Degrade gracefully FTW.

Answer (score -1):

you can use programs given in the link [look here](http://blog.ubuntu-tweak.com/2007/09/30/how-to-control-ubuntus-services-easily.html) and [here](http://www.debuntu.org/how-to-manage-services-with-update-rc.d)

Comment: Please refrain from dumping links. It does not help when people search this website and links tend to rot.